# Disable the escape key in dojo

Tags: dojo, dialog, keypress

I have a requirement to disable the escape key when the dialog is open.currently when i click the escape button the dialog closes and the transaction is submitting.I tried the following code snippet but its not working chrome.

```javascript
                    dojo.connect(dialog, "onKeyPress", function(e){ 
                    var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode; 
                    var k = dojo.keys; 

                    if (key == k.ESCAPE) { 
                         event.preventDefault();

                     d.stopEvent(event);
                    } 
                    });
```

Could you please help on this..i have searched a lot and havent found a suitable solution for my problem.
Thanks inadvance..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dojo uses the `_onKey` event for accessibility. You can override it by using:

```
dialog._onKey = function() { }
```

I wrote an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkVnw/), hitting the Escape key should not work anymore.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri M..i did extend my dialog with the new dialog._onKey with the code i intended to do..its working now..thanks a ton...

Answer (score 3):

In the event you want to override the escape key in all dialogs (rather than a particular instance), you can use [dojo/aspect](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/aspect):

```javascript
require(['dojo/aspect', 'dijit/Dialog'], function (Aspect, Dialog) {
    Aspect.around(Dialog.prototype, '_onKey', function (original) {
        return function () { }; // no-op
    });
});
```

Comment: That can be very annoying for other developers if nobody know about this. I would rather choose for extending the dialog (like @Ramesh did in the end) than manipulating it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension for the Dialog widget like this in a new file:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/Dialog"],
    function(declare, Dialog){
    return declare(Dialog, {

        //Prevents the 'ESC' Button of Closing the dialog
        _onKey: function() { }

    });
});
```

save the file into dojo Directory (say: dojo/my/my_dialog.js),
and instead of calling: 'dijit/Dialog', just call: 'my/my_dialog'.
this will save you the hard work of editing each Dialog call,
**And the same thing to the "dojox/widget/DialogSimple" Widget.**